# Understanding the code flow: diamond operator and anonymous class

Tags: java, generic-programming, anonymous-class

I learned that from Java 9 it's possible to use the diamond operator while creating an anonymous class only if the type argument is inferable

After that, I don't understand this code, it's from Java Generic Programming theory

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Main {
    public static <T> Iterable<T> getIterable(T... elems) {
        return new Iterable<T>() {

            @Override
            public Iterator<T> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<>() {
                    int i = 0;

                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return i < elems.length;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public T next() {
                        if(!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
                        return elems[i++];
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String[] path = {"UP", "DOWN", "LEFT", "RIGHT"};

        Iterable<String> ipaths = getIterable(path);

        for (String apath : ipaths) {
            System.out.println(apath);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how this code work, I tried with debugger but it's still really strange to me, the first "return new Iterator()" in my IntellijIDEA is in grey, seems like it's treated like a comment

My knowledge about anonymous class is just a simple creation like that

```
Example ex = new Example() {
    //fields
   // no constructor 
   //method, overriden method from the superclass
   };
```

Comment: Are you asking how the compiler can infer that the type argument for `new Iterator<>()`  is `T`? It can infer that from the return type of the method. --- If that's not what you're asking, then please **edit** the question and clarify exactly what it is you're asking.

Comment: The return new Iterable<T>() is in grey in intelij because you can use a lambda for that

Comment: Hover your mouse over "new Iterable<T>()" and it will tell you why it has greyed that code.

Comment: I could replace the "grey" code with a lambda but I don't know a lot about lambda, so I just want an explanation about this code, what it do to obtain the output

Comment: A lambda can be used to quickly create an anonymous class implementing an interface that only has 1 method, if that interface can be inferred. For example, a function that takes a `Predicate` can be passed a lambda as an argument instead of writing an anonymous class with loads of boilerplate.